# Which version of WebSphere supports JPA 2.1?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, websphere, compatibility, java-ee-7

Which version of WebSphere  supports JPA 2.1 and hibernate 5? and how to find the compatibility matrix of WebSphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server): this is *8.5 Liberty Profile, 9.0 and WebSphere Liberty (Continuous Delivery)*.